# How to set up the React native in development mode with unminified

Tags: react-native

Some help would be appreciated with the following issue:

I'm trying to get the non-minified output. For some reason, I keep getting `Error: Minified React error` even when I run the app in development mode.

I can open the development tools and with the code below I can see *Development* is printed in the console.

```
if (__DEV__) {
    console.log('Development');
} else {
    console.log('Production');
}
```

I started the project with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` and made an error.

How can i set up the non-minified dev environment.

When I used a template project with expo and did an eject to react native it was using the the non-minified dev environment. Can someone explain how i can set this up on the creation of a new project with npx?

Answer (score 1):

Having an incorrect import was causing this issue.

I let IntelliJ import `useState` without verifying it.

Changing the import from:

```
import {useState} from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';
```

To

```
import {useState} from 'react';
```

fixes the issues.